# Keep Windows Script in same Command Window

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have the following script which does the following on a Virtuozzo hardware node.
: Get Running VEs
: Prompt for VEID
: Get Established Connections on Port 3389 for Specified VEID
: Prompt for IP to Block
: Create IP Security Policy to Block Specified IP
: Reset Terminal Sessions

So everything works the way I want except I can't figure out how to have everything occur in a single cmd prompt rather than spawning new command prompts.  If I remove the cmd /K from the exec commands then nothing is displayed.  Am I missing something simple?

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")

getrunningvelistcmd = "cmd /K echo 'List Running VEs' & vzlist -a | find ""running"""
getrunningvelist = oShell.run (getrunningvelistcmd,1,false)

strVEID = InputBox("Enter VEID","Enter VEID")

whosethebrutecmd = "cmd /K echo 'Whose the Brute' & vzctl exec "&strVEID & " netstat -ano | find "":3389""" 
whosethebrute = oShell.run (whosethebrutecmd,1,false)

strIP = InputBox("Enter IP Address to Block","Enter IP Address to Block")

blockcmd = "cmd /K echo 'Create Policy' & vzctl exec "&strVEID & " netsh ipsec static add policy description=""Block Rule"" name=""Blocked Traffic"" && echo. && echo 'Create Filter List' && vzctl exec "&strVEID & " netsh ipsec static add filterlist name=""IP Block List"" && echo. && echo 'Create Filter' && vzctl exec "&strVEID & " netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist=""IP Block List"" srcaddr="&strIP & " dstaddr=any description=""Hacker IP"" && echo. && echo 'Define Filter Action' && vzctl exec "&strVEID & " netsh ipsec static add filteraction name=""Block"" action=block && echo. && echo 'Add Rule to Filter Action' && vzctl exec "&strVEID & " netsh ipsec static add rule name=""Block Rule"" policy=""Blocked Traffic"" filterlist=""IP Block List"" filteraction=""Block"" activate=yes && echo. && echo 'Assign Policy' && vzctl exec "&strVEID & " netsh ipsec static set policy name=""Blocked Traffic"" assign=yes && echo. && echo. && echo 'Reset Sessions PRESS ENTER' && vzctl exec "&strVEID & " rwinsta rdp-tcp && echo. && echo 'You Terminated the Brute!'"
blockthebrute = oShell.run (blockcmd,1,false)  

set oShell =  Nothing 
WScript.Quit(0)
```

Comment: Can you prompt for all the user input in advance?

Comment: no, the input is based off of the windows.  for example it first shows all the VEs from which you enter the VEID, then it shows the established connections from which you enter the IP address to block

Comment: Are you running this with cscript or wscript?

Answer (score 0):

The 'programmatically correct way' to solve your problem is to write a .hta GUI. But if you are willing to use cscript to run your script, you may get an acceptable UI without to much work. As I don't have your *ware, this POC script:

' bstep00.vbs - keep-windows-script-in-same-command-window

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWSH : Set oWSH = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Dim sCmd, oEx, sFN, iRet

sCmd = "fkdir.bat"
Set oEx = oWSH.Exec( sCmd )
If Not oEx.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
   WScript.Echo oEx.StdOut.ReadAll()
   WScript.StdOut.Write "file to type: "
   sFN = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   sCmd = "fktype.bat " & sFN
   Set oEx = oWSH.Exec( sCmd )
   If Not oEx.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
      WScript.Echo oEx.StdOut.ReadAll()
   Else
      WScript.Echo "(1) oEx.StdOut.AtEndOfStream"
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo "(0) oEx.StdOut.AtEndOfStream"
End If
WScript.Echo "Done."
```

uses `dir` (get/show info) and `type` (use user's input based on info) to demonstrate the components: .Exec and .bat files (like

```
fktype.bat:
@echo off
type %1
```

). Using .bat (or .cmd) files solves 2 problems: "complex command lines" and "%comspec% starting", so don't be tempted to avoid them by putting more text into sCmd.

Output of sample session:

```
cscript bstep00.vbs
07.10.2011  13:48                29 fkdir.bat
07.10.2011  14:01                20 fktype.bat

file to type: fkdir.bat
@echo off
dir | find "bat"

Done.
```